# Improper synchronization between the client and host Animation in Unity's netcode

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, networking, multiplayer

"How can I resolve the problem of animations constantly going back and forth instead of staying synchronized between the client and host in Unity's netcode, even though I've added the owner network animator script and client network transform script?"

Attached the player controller Script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using Unity.Netcode;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class PlayerController : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public PlayerController parent;

    //public player parent;
    private CharacterController _controller;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _playerSpeed = 5f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _rotationSpeed = 10f;

    [SerializeField]
    private Camera _followCamera;

    public bool isWalking;
    public Animator playerAnimator;

    public float WaterHeight = 15.5f;
    float gravity = -9.8f;


    private Vector3 _playerVelocity;
    private bool _groundedPlayer;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _jumpHeight = 1.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float _gravityValue = -9.81f;


    private List<GameObject> spawnedObjects = new List<GameObject>();

    private void OnEnable()
    {

    }

    private void Start()
    {
        _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) return;
        //if ( !Application.isFocused) return;

        Movement();
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter()
    {

        //int clientId = ConnectionToClient.connectionId;
        Debug.Log(OwnerClientId+"iiiiiiiiiiiiiiddddddddddddddddddddddddddd");

    }


    void Movement()
    { 
        _groundedPlayer = _controller.isGrounded;
        if (_groundedPlayer && _playerVelocity.y < 0)
        {
            _playerVelocity.y = 0f;
        }

        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    
        Vector3 movementInput = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput);
        Vector3 movementDirection = movementInput.normalized;

        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0f, verticalInput).normalized;  //new
        transform.position += direction * _playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;  // new



        //_controller.Move(movementDirection * _playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
        //_controller.SimpleMove(movementDirection * _playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 

        bool hasHorizontalInput = !Mathf.Approximately(horizontalInput, 0f);
        bool hasVerticalInput = !Mathf.Approximately(verticalInput, 0f);

        isWalking = hasHorizontalInput || hasVerticalInput;

        bool isRunning = (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift));
        playerAnimator.SetBool("IsRunning", isRunning);

        bool isAttack = (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0));

        playerAnimator.SetBool("isAttack", isAttack);
   
        playerAnimator.SetBool("isWalking", isWalking);

      
        if (movementDirection != Vector3.zero)
        {
            Quaternion desiredRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movementDirection, Vector3.up);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, desiredRotation, _rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        
    }
}
```

I tried replacing the line "_controller.Move(movementDirection * _playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);" with the following code:

Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0f, verticalInput).normalized;
transform.position += direction * _playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

By implementing the code changes as mentioned above, I observed a significant reduction in synchronization errors, with the occurrence being reduced by approximately 50%.